# How to add my own translations to my vuetify 2.x web app?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I'm currently writing my first web app with vuetify 2.x and vue-i18n. Unfortunately I can't get i18n working for my own translations.

I have a menu with the following entry

```html
      <v-menu bottom left offset-y transition="slide-y-transition">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn icon v-on="on">
            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item @click="showAllItems">
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ $vuetify.lang.t("cancelFilters") }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item @click="showNonZeroItems">
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ $vuetify.lang.t("maskZero") }}
            </v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
```

But the keys are displayed instead of the English or other language. I set English as the fallback language.

The function exist and is working, but my translations are not taken in account.

This is the content of `src/locales/en.json`. I wasn't sure if keys may contain spaces.

```json
{
  "search": "Search",
  "cancelFilters": "Cancel filters",
  "maskZero": "Mask zero counts",
  "maskUnchecked": "Mask unchecked",
  "maskChecked": "Mask checked",
  "sharingCode": "Sharing code",
  "preferences": "Preferences",
  "addList": "Add list",
  "disconnect": "Disconnect",
  "sponsoringLink": "Sponsoring link"
}
```

I saw that the json files in the locales directory are all loaded in the `src/i18n.js` file.

What are the missing steps required to get my translations ?

How can I change the current language ?

**Solution**: I found out how to use my own translations defined in en.json. Simply replace `$vuetify.lang.t`by `$i18n.t`. As simple as that. It still remains to find how to change the current language.

Comment: I'm not sure where you saw the use of a json file for vuetifys translator.
The [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/#creating-a-translation) provide a slightly different approach where you'd create a plain js/ts file that inherits vuetifys translations and your's added on top.
Those are then passed to the vuetify plugin in it's options.
Seems to me that you just skipped vuetifys now and went straight to i18n instead, which is okay too ^^

Comment: It is the vue cli installation with the i18n option selected that installed the `src/locales`directory and the example `en.json`file in it. I found the json file convenient because it makes it simple to manipulate. A translator knowing nothing of javascript could do it. Apparently this is how i18n is integrated in vuetify. The `$vuetify.lang.t`is for vuetify translations. I wished the vuetify documentation also showed how to use the `$i18n.t` function with the json files. It is also more concise. I must now explore its capabilities.

Comment: Mh... looks like you just installed two translators. Vuetify comes with one and you added the one via vue cli. Instead of using the vuetify one you're using i18n now, like I said above.
But tbh it probably doesn't matter too much and as long as you get the results you want, go with that =)

Comment: `$i18n.t` is from vue-i18n, not vuetify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$vuetify.lang` is just a lightweight implementation designed to be used internally by Vuetify's components to translate strings like v-select's `no-data-text`. These props can take plain strings (`no-data-text="There's nothing here"`) as well as translation keys, so keys need to be prefixed with `$vuetify` (`no-data-text="$vuetify.noDataText"`).

Obviously this isn't very usable and doesn't give you much flexibility, so for translating the rest of your site we recommend using [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) instead. We also show how to store customised vuetify translations in the vue-i18n json files: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/internationalization/#vue-i18n

Comment: The documentation is lacking a usage example in a template. It is also lacking an explanation that the json files in `src/locales/` are automatically imported as messages. I have a small app and loading all translations is not a problem. But with big apps I assume that lazy loading of translations is preferable. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Vuetify doesn't do any of that, the json files belong to vue-i18n